# How to make radio buttons with same value reusable?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I am a beginner to Vue, and learning something by doing. I was able to make a checkbox reusable, but getting some weird result for radio buttons.
I have the data in an array format in `ProgramDesign.vue`:

```js
data() {
  return {
    strategies: [
      "Not Important",
      "Slightly Important",
      "Moderately Important",
      "Very Important",
      "Extremely Important",
    ],
  };
},
```

These are the options that get repeated on every question.
I made a separate component for the radio like this:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <span v-for="strategy in groups" :key="strategy">
      <input :id="strategy" class="radio-style" name="strategy" type="radio" />
      <label :for="strategy" class="radio-style-3-label">{{strategy}}</label>
    </span>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    groups: Array,
  },
};
</script>
```

This is how it's used in `ProgramDesign.vue`:

```html
<p>first question goes here ?</p>
<RadioButton :groups="strategies" />
<div class="line"></div>
<p>second question goes here ?</p>
<RadioButton :groups="strategies" />
```

I was able to get the reusable output, but when I click on the radio button for the second question, the buttons for the first question get selected. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the `input` IDs and names are not unique between component instances, as can be seen in the rendering of your two `RadioButton` components (simplified for brevity):

```html
<!-- RadioButton 1 -->
<div>
  <span>
    <input id="Not Important" name="strategy" type="radio">
    <label for="Not Important">Not Important</label>
  </span>
</div>

<!-- RadioButton 2 -->
<div>
  <span>
    <input id="Not Important"❌ name="strategy"❌ type="radio">
    <label for="Not Important">Not Important</label>
  </span>
</div>
```

Each `label` is linked to an `input` by matching the `for` and `id` attributes, such that clicking the `label` causes the linked radio `input` to change values. When there are multiple `input`s with the same identifier, the browser links the `label` to the *first* matching `input`, causing the behavior you observed.

The `name` must also be unique between groups (`RadioButton` instances), since the browser creates radio groups of `input`s that have matching names.

#### Solution

Alternatively, a `label` and `input` can be linked by putting the `input` inside the `label`, resolving the `id`/`for` duplication (and improving readability):

```html
<label>
  <input name="strategy" type="radio">
  Not Important
</label>
```

And one way to resolve the duplicate `name`s is to base the name on a counter incremented per instance:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <label v-for="strategy in groups" :key="strategy">
      <input :name="'strategy' + groupId" type="radio">
      {{strategy}}
    </label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
let groupId = 0

export default {
  props: {
    groups: Array
  },
  data() {
    return {
      groupId: groupId++
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[image: Edit Troubleshooting label and input pairs]

Comment: Thank you @tony19. This is the best answer that I could receive. Made me more clear regarding the link between a `label` and `input`  and works perfectly.